# Can cross-sliding be used in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winjs

I need to allow users to 'cross-slide' on items in list boxes **in WPF**. This functionality is available in the Windows Store UI (WinJS?), and the Microsoft guidelines are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465299.aspx).

The guidelines pretty much describe what cross-sliding is.

Are there any existing implementations for this, or do I need to create my own?

I have done multiple days of research, and I haven't found anything :/ Any help much appreciated :)

Comment: It's not built in. You'd need to build it or buy it, or write a Windows Store app.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Could you please post that as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not built in. You'd need to build it, buy it (there may be a third party toolkit that offers similar behavior), or create a Windows Store application.